# WPF GridView adjust width to available space size

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I have an ListView in my WPF application

```
<ListView Name="generatorsList" ItemsSource="{Binding GeneratorsList}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Name">Name</GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Actions" Width="60">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        //buttons
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Which looks like this
[image: current with big window]

The case is, when window is smaller than the list itself (for example if description is very long like in shown example) the scrollbar is formed and `GridView` stays the same, so action buttons are not visible at the screen (user must drag the scrollbar).
[image: current with small window]

I would like to set an maximum column width based on current window width at initialization so the `Actions` column will always appear when the ListView is shown to user. Like that
[image: expected result]

And then if user wants to, he can manually resize any column (so no actual "`maxwidth`" is set, just `width`).
I've tried to work with `*` but GridView does not know about its children so `*` is not working here, `auto` is not a good option becouse I cannot set the maximum desired width per column, also constant width value is unwanted becouse it must depend on window size (available space size) which is variable. I assume I need some kind of event in code behind but I don't know how it should be handled in proper way.

Comment: you could always place the Actions at the front: this way, they are always at the same location, regardless of window or column width.

Comment: it will work but it's a trick. Lists does not look well with action buttons in the front. Also what if `Name` field is too long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="generatorsList" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding GeneratorsList}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" 
                            Binding="{Binding Name}"
                            Width="*"/>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" 
                            Binding="{Binding Type}"/>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" 
                            Binding="{Binding Description}"
                            Width="2*"/>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actions"
                                Width="auto"
                                MinWidth="60">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--buttons-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have changed your ListView into DataGrid (better for this case in my opinion).

Comment: It resizing itself as intended but it went like this: https://imgur.com/a/G9SWa
It seems that the `DataGrid` added all source item properties itself, any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about this. `DataGrid` generates columns based on `ItemsSource` automatically. Just set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` on your `DataGrid` and you will be fine. (I have also edited my answer to contain this fix)

Comment: Now it's working fine, thanks! Also for my own needs I've added those properties to the DataGrid `Background="Transparent" GridLinesVisibility="None" CanUserResizeRows="False" 
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single"`

Comment: Styling to meet your needs is up to you :) I'd suggest you to look through all poperties, because `DataGrid` have a lot of functionalities and many of them can not be so good to have turned on in your case. It also supports scrolling, so if you need it, you can test changing properties under `ScrollViewer` property of your `DataGrid` (if I remember correctly, it will turn vertical `ScrollBar` on once your content overflows your control vertically).